# converting a string column into integer while reading data (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i'm trying to read a .txt file but i also want to convert a column (**Age**) from string to **np.int64** format. This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(source + 'clustering_CB\\Export_Customer_base_LI.txt' ,sep='\t' , engine='python' , dtype = {'Day' : np.datetime64 , 'Age' : np.int64}  )
```

i get this  value error:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert column Age to type <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Any help?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Maybe if upgrade get better error.

Comment: how can i find my pandas's version?

Comment: Run *pd.show_versions()*. And include a sample of your source file.